# Windows Phone 8.1 override back button when message dialog is open

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

i have a message dialog which shows two button nav-to-page1 and nav-to-page2 button, means i have restrict user to either navigate to page1 or page2.

i am facing a problem in case when mesage dialog is open and back button is press this behaviour close my message dialog.

i can override back button in case when message dialog is not open. i want to overide back button when dialog is open.

```
MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to quit you will loose all your work ?", "Warning");
dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("nav-to-page1", new UICommandInvokedHandler(CommandHandler1)));
dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("nav-to-page2", new UICommandInvokedHandler(CommandHandler1)));

await dlg.ShowAsync();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Closing of messagedialog on Backkeypress is default. Dont think you can override this behavior as it does not hit backkeypress method when messagedialog is open. One suggestion: right now when you press back button it takes it as command and enters into "CommandHandler1" method. To avoid this while creating command, add some command id like

```
private async void gv_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gvi = sender as GridView;
        MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to quit you will loose all your work ?", "Warning");
        dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("nav-to-page1", new UICommandInvokedHandler(CommandHandler1), 0));
        dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("nav-to-page2", new UICommandInvokedHandler(CommandHandler1),1));

        await dlg.ShowAsync();
    }



    private void CommandHandler1(IUICommand command)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```